# Acceder a carpetas de volumen creado por docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Tengo el siguiente docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    labels:
      - com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

  www:
    image: aguidev/website:v1.2
    restart: always
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=3000
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=midominio.com.ar
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=midominio.com.ar
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=mimail.com.ar
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
      - letsencrypt

  mail:
    image: analogic/poste.io
    ports:
      - "25:25"
      - "110:110"
      - "143:143"
      - "465:465"
      - "587:587"
      - "993:993"
      - "995:995"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
      - letsencrypt
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=mail.midominio.com.ar
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80 #webmail
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=mail.midominio.com.ar
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=mimail.com.ar
      - HTTPS=OFF
      - DISABLE_CLAMAV=TRUE

volumes:
  certs:
  html:
  vhostd:
```

Ahora bien, lo que necesito es agregar un volumen al servicio "mail" de una carpeta que se encuentra dentro del volumen creado "CERTS" este corresponde a los certificados q se crean en el contenedor "nginx-proxy"
Es correcto declarar :

```
 mail:
        image: analogic/poste.io
        ports:
          - "25:25"
          - "110:110"
          - "143:143"
          - "465:465"
          - "587:587"
          - "993:993"
          - "995:995"
        volumes:
          - ./data:/data
          - **certs/mail.midominio.com.ar:/data/ssl**
        restart: always
        depends_on:
          - nginx-proxy
          - letsencrypt
        environment:
          - TZ=America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires
          - VIRTUAL_HOST=mail.midominio.com.ar
          - VIRTUAL_PORT=80 #webmail
          - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=mail.midominio.com.ar
          - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=mimail.com.ar
          - HTTPS=OFF
          - DISABLE_CLAMAV=TRUE
```

¿Es correcto este metodo o debo acceder directamente al volumen cuando ya esta montado en la carpeta "/var/lib/docker/volumes"?

O cual ser la practica correcta?
He consultado la documentación de Docker pero solo indica como crear los volúmenes y como acceder a ellos cuando se generan de la forma que los estoy declarando yo.

Agradezco su tiempo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no es posible lo que dices. Pero puedes intentar y mirar si se funciona. Puedes decir una solución alternativa. Primeramente, montar todo el volumen en una ruta separada y luego vincularlo a la ruta secundaria.

```
# En Dockerfile de mail:
RUN mkdir -p /data/subdir
RUN ln -s /data/subdir /data/ssl
```

Luego monte el volumen en docker composer.
El /subdir debe existir en el volumen.

```
certs:/data
```